# <project name> is not an App Engine project when attempting to deploy

Tags: python, google-app-engine, setup-project

I'm getting this error when I attempt to deploy my python project for the first time.  I could have sworn that I set everything up correctly.  Is there something I need to set in the configuration?  I have not idea where to start looking, any help would be appreciated.

[image: screen capture]

This is my `app.yaml` file.  It resides in the `src` folder:

```
application: bsl-dm
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1
```

**EDIT:** After looking into this, I think the solution is that you cannot do this for python through eclipse (only java).  You instead have to use the separate "Google App Engine Launcher" application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got your problem. I think you are using google plugin to deploy the app which expects an java application. It won't work for python applications. To deploy python app engine app from eclipse use pydev plugin. A search on google will get you there

Comment: Good catch. That would certainly explain it.

Answer (score 3):

This got me too! I assumed the button in the toolbar could be used for Python too but it was only for java.

In eclipse(which im guessing its the same in Aptana) once you have the pydev plugin installed simply right click on your apps main folder and go to "PyDev: Google App Engine" and click 'Upload'

Comment: Note: this worked if I right clicked on the Src folder within the project, not if I right clicked on the top level Project folder itself

Answer (score 1):

You have a register a unique application id in appengine.google.com for your account inorder to deploy the same.You will see something like this where you have to choose a id and register it. Make sure you have mentioned the same in your app.yaml.
[image: appengine]

Comment: I've actually already done this.  The problem seems to be on my side, somewhere in the application setup.  The app.yaml file is in the "src" folder.  Is this the right place?

Comment: Ya app.yaml resides in the src folder. i think you should post your app.yaml

Comment: Cool, I just posted the app.yaml file

Answer (score 0):

Have you reserved that app-id at https://appengine.google.com/ ?

Comment: Yeah I have.  I'm not positive about this, but I think the problem is happening before it even contacts the servers.